# Java Web Services - Intacct Application

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I am new to Java environment. I have to create a java utility to extract information from an external application using web-services.For that I need to send an XML request and receive the response. I am browsing around the web and couldn't find any better article. I want to know how to send a XML request and print the request and the response using Java. Any good reference should also help.

Comment: It's not that difficult to google: rest+xml+java+example one of the first links leads to [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) which contains some great hands-on tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using Java, you should check out the Java specifications for

1. [JAX-RS](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr339/index.html): Spec for Java REST services
2. [JAX-WS](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr224/): Spec for Java XML Web services (this roughly is the SOAP spec)

Both of these topics are extensive.  FWIW REST seems to be the style-of-choice today.  SOAP was prevalent several years back, but for several reasons (simplicity, ease of implementation), REST has  surpassed SOAP.  Of course if you have a target web service in mind, the style of the service makes the REST/SOAP choice for you.